# Why are these bootstrap buttons touching each other?

Tags: bootstrap-4

These two bootstrap buttons touch each other. Do I need to add some custom CSS to get some space between them? The docs here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/buttons/ don't touch each other.

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <form>
    <div class="btn-toolbar">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-u5zg9m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the buttons are touching each other because you are putting them in a `btn-toolbar` (by the way `btn-group` will do the same). You can eather remove it or use CSS to add margin.

Comment: That solved it for that one, why are they still touching here? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h55y1q?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: it is different if you use angular. You need to add mr-1 to your first button class (<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-1">Submit</button>) or use css. check out this link https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/components/buttons-group/

Answer (score 2):

You can add:

```
    <div class="btn-toolbar" style="display: inline">
```

so that your code looks like this:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <form>
    <div class="btn-toolbar" style="display: inline">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet" 
integrity="sha384ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form>
       <div class="btn-toolbar">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-1">Submit</button>
           <button type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary">Reset</button>
       </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

just add a margin using mr-1 on the submit button or ml-1 to the reset button